# Memory error with simple for loop merging series onto a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have written a  function to perform a rolling sum on multiple columns then append the new rolling summed series as a column on the original data frame. Simple enough.

```
def rolling_sum(df, columns, w=3):

'''insert rolling sum for each column in list of columns for window (w) in months. '''

    for column in columns:

        print column + 'sum'+ str(3)

        df.index = df.date
        series = df.groupby(['pixel']).rolling(w)[column].sum() # no year. so rolls over dec-jan
        series = series.reset_index(level=[0,1])
        series.rename(index=str, columns={column: column + 'sum' + str(w)}, inplace=True)
        #df = df.merge(series, on=['pixel','date']) # unnecessary
        df = df.merge(series)

        print 'successful merge'

    return df
```

And 'lo 'n behold it works with one dataframe (1 GB) and it kind of works on another (They are merging on the exact same columns-- both an object 'date' [2012-06] and float64 'pixel' [1000.1]).

The semi failing case seems to be eating up RAM profusely after the second or third column. It is as if it is storing a bunch of unnecessary memory somehow. This df is only 100 MB and I have tried downsizing it to 10 MB and it still does the same thing, but makes it to the fourth column or so.

Any ideas on how to trouble shoot this thing?

Comment: Is this being done in jupyter?

Comment: How many elements are in 'columns'?

Comment: spyder. [518050 rows x 15 columns]

Comment: See if this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051210/avoiding-memory-issues-for-groupby-on-large-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Groupby loops can be very taxing to store in memory, but dask.dataframes allow this to be done in parallel.

Comment: Interesting. I will try the dask.dataframes. It is unusually becaues the df I am working with is much smaller than one that already succesfully went through this function.